# Why I can’t use zoom+ or zoom- in firefox4 in mac‘s Multi-Touch Touchpad?

Tags: mac, firefox, zoom

I can use zoom function in firefox3 and safari,but when I update to firefox4,I find I can’t use the zoom function ,how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/fixing-firefox-4-8217s-mac-multi-touch-woes/864).